# Line with fill and stroke

Tags: wpf, xaml, line

I'm trying to create a line that looks like this in wpf.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I need to bind the x and y coordinates, so a line works really well except I can't make it look like this.

[image: Line with outline and fill]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this with a simple line, but with a `Border` object it is very easy.

```
<Border Width="100" Height="10" Background="#FFFFDAAD" BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="0,3"/>
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like I can get the look I'm after but I really need to bind to x1,x2,y1,y2 like on the line.

Comment: You can bind x1 to Canvas.Left and y1 to Canvas.Top of the border.  For x2 and y2, you would need to implement a ValueConverter to change x1,x2 into Width and y1,y2 into Height.

Answer (score 2):

You can overlay multiple Lines, Polylines or Polygons to achieve similar effects and use resources to avoid duplication, for example (just inspiration):

```xml
<Canvas ClipToBounds="True" Height="200" Width="200">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <PointCollection x:Key="Wings">0,-2 62,-2 62,22 58,22 58,2 0,2</PointCollection>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <Polygon Points="{StaticResource Wings}" Fill="Black" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="4"/>
    <Polygon Points="{StaticResource Wings}" StrokeThickness="8" Stroke="White"/>
    <Polygon Points="{StaticResource Wings}" StrokeThickness="4" Stroke="Red"/>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have best solution, make for "outline" line StrokeThickness more than "simple" line:

```
      <Line x:Name="borderLine" X1="0" X2="400" Y1="0" Y2="0" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="White"/>
      <Line x:Name="borderOutlineLine" X1="0" X2="400" Y1="0" Y2="0" StrokeThickness="0.3" Stroke="Black"/>
```