# Drawing lines in WPF on DrawingContext with outer lines

Tags: c#, wpf, line, drawingcontext

I'm trying to draw a lot of similar kind of lines in WPF as seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642395/line-with-fill-and-stroke) question, but the difference is that I need to draw it on a DrawingContext of a DrawingVisual object. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to draw two lines between identical points on top of each other, the lower with a thicker pen, the upper with a thinner pen.

```
Pen background = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 5);
Pen foreground = new Pen(Brushes.White, 3);

drawingContext.DrawLine(background, new Point(100, 100), new Point(200, 200));
drawingContext.DrawLine(foreground, new Point(100, 100), new Point(200, 200));
```

This lines look at lot better when you also define the pen line caps:

```
Pen background = new Pen
{
    Brush = Brushes.Black,
    Thickness = 5,
    StartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round,
    EndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round
};

Pen foreground = new Pen
{
    Brush = Brushes.White,
    Thickness = 3,
    StartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round,
    EndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round
};
```

With an extension method like this

```
public static class DrawingContextExtensions
{
    public static void DrawLine(this DrawingContext drawingContext,
        Pen background, Pen foreground, Point start, Point end)
    {
        drawingContext.DrawLine(background, start, end);
        drawingContext.DrawLine(foreground, start, end);
    }
}
```

you could do the drawing in one call:

```
drawingContext.DrawLine(background, foreground, new Point(100, 100), new Point(200, 200));
```